# Is it possible to create a unified client that manages multiple cryptocurrencies?

Tags: wallet, currencies

Is it possible to create a unified client that manages multiple cryptocurrencies? Does such a client already exist?

Answer (score 1):

[MuCoWa](http://mucowa.com/) is a multicoin wallet that supports BTC, LTC, DOGE, QRK, FTC, CGA, and DGC. They charge 0.15% fees to send though.

Comment: Yup its pretty straightforward When you consider that add o far all but a few crypto coins uttilose an identical rpc.  Meaning that the implementation would be pretty straight forward.  You would still need to download the block chain for each additional coin.